Offloading a multi-dimensional operation to the GPU using OpenMP
I'm trying to perform multi dimensional openmp target offloading but I keep either getting segmentation faults, or a wrong result. Also - much worse performance compared to not using GPUs (which shouldn't happen since I'm using several strong GPUs). Here's a sample code I'm trying to optimize:
static double (*u)[JMAXP+1][IMAXP+1][5]=(double(*)[JMAXP+1][IMAXP+1][5])malloc(sizeof(double)*((KMAX)*(JMAXP+1)*(IMAXP+1)*(5)));
static double (*rhs)[JMAXP+1][IMAXP+1][5]=(double(*)[JMAXP+1][IMAXP+1][5])malloc(sizeof(double)*((KMAX)*(JMAXP+1)*(IMAXP+1)*(5)));


void add(){
    int i, j, k, m;
    int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

    if(timeron && thread_id==0){timer_start(T_ADD);}
    #pragma omp for
    for(k=1; k<=grid_points[2]-2; k++){
        for(j=1; j<=grid_points[1]-2; j++){
            for(i=1; i<=grid_points[0]-2; i++){
                for(m=0; m<5; m++){
                    u[k][j][i][m]=u[k][j][i][m]+rhs[k][j][i][m];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(timeron && thread_id==0){timer_stop(T_ADD);}
}


I tried to replace pragma omp for with pragma omp target the run finished but I got the wrong result and a longer runtime. When I tried replacing it with pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for collapse(3) map(tofrom: u[:KMAX][:JMAXP+1][:IMAXP+1][:5]) map(to:rhs[:KMAX][:JMAXP+1][:IMAXP+1][:5]) I am getting a segmentation fault.
What am I doing wrong? I couldn't find a good example on how to offload a function that performs a multi-dimensional operation (using OpenMP) anywhere.
I'd appreciate your assistance. Thanks!

Your code is clearly memory bound. There is no chance for this code to be faster on GPU if data are not already stored on the device. Host/Device data transfers are always slower than the RAM (especially in PCIe) and a good CPU code should already saturate it. Thus, using a map on this set of loop will always result in a slower execution at best compared to a parallel CPU code. You need to change your code to avoid such horrible access pattern (e.g. loop marching, tiling, etc.). Memory accesses are expensive, even on GPUs.

That may be true, but I'm not sure if that answers my questions. What I asked was why replacing the pragma with the others I suggested would either result with a wrong answer or cause a segmentation fault. Once I don't get either of those I'll gladly address the issues you brought up to further optimize the code.

I just answered your point about "much worse performance",hence a simple comment and not an answer. IDK for the other points. I think you should add the compiler used and its version as well as the exact target device. Bugs are quite common on this part of OpenMP which is still barely supported and only recently for mainstream compilers (some still do not support it).

I also advise you to check if a the OpenMP examples using device directives work properly on your environnement.

Besides, it seems you are already running this from a parallel section. Using omp target directive from a parallel section will certainly execute the code N times from the N OpenMP thread. I think you should use a omp master or omp single directive to avoid this.
